# Почему admin-ajax.php возвращает -1 на wp_signon?

Tags: wordpress

Есть вот такая функция

```
    function ajax_login(){

    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

  auth_user_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], 'Login'); 

    die();
}

function auth_user_login($user_login, $password, $login)
{
  $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $user_login;
    $info['user_password'] = $password;
    $info['remember'] = true;

  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
    wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID);
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__($login.' successful, redirecting...')));
    }

  die();
}
```

На одном сайте у меня она работает отлично, ставлю на второй и при попытке входа admin-ajax.php возвращает "-1"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем нужно сказать у меня прописаны такие же функции на восстановление и регистрацию аккаунта и так вот они работают нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. 
У заказчика был установлен и зачем то скрыт плагин PA Modal Login 
Вот он и блокировал...